# Limit with sum of powers and a constant

Tags: limits

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}, (a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n-1 \ne0$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = 1$. I am looking for
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}{a_n + a_n^2 + \dots + a_n^k - k \over a_n - 1}$$
Do you have any suggestions?

I have tried using the sum of the first $n$ terms of the geometric series and to multiply both the numerator and denominator by $a_n-1$. Both approaches still leave me with a zero limit in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try rearranging the numerator into something more suitable like $(a_n-1)+(a_n^2-1)+\dots+(a_n^k-1)$